# Signifyd credit card antifraud service Integration in X-Cart 5

Tags: php, x-cart

I'm trying to implement a third party library - **signifyd** for my client. Signifyd is a third party service for credit card fraud prevention.

I created a X-Payments trial account for testing purpose and enabled authorizenet payment method(sandbox mode). Then I installed xpaymentsconnector module in my xcart store.

Now I need to fetch credit card details that customer entered and pass those informations with order details to api.

I checked xpaymentsconnector module.

```
$info = $this->client->requestPaymentInfo($transaction->getDataCell('xpc_txnid')->getValue());
```

Above code returns basic paymnet info. Refer: https://www.x-payments.com/help/X-Payments:Payment_information_request

```
$info = $this->client->requestPaymentAdditionalInfo($transaction->getDataCell('xpc_txnid')->getValue());
```

This is the xpaymnetconnector api call to fetch additional info. Refer: https://www.x-payments.com/help/X-Payments:Detailed_payment_and_transaction_information_request. As per doc it returns all details including cardholder name.

I tried to call PaymentAdditionalInfo API but it doesn't return cardholdername. I tried it with sample code also. Getting same result. why it doesnot return cardholder name or it returns name for live transaction only?
How can I retrieve cardholder name also.

Comment: what's your question? Have you tried and encountered a problem that you need help with? If you want someone to implement the whole solution I think it will cost you more than some upvotes :-)

Comment: Hi @ADyson, signifyd is a fraud protection service for ecommerce. When customer purchase order with his credit card details, these datas need to be passed to signifyd. Signifyd checks if all infos are valid or not. I have implemented it in basic php. I don't know where should I place my code.

Comment: Do you mean you've written some code to call the API and you don't know where to put it in your solution? I commented because your post does not actually include a question, only a very vague statement which does not indicate what you have done already, or indicate any specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

Actually X-Cart 5 never touches credit card information so it is hard to say how you can submit this type of data to Signifyd. You would need to integrate Signifyd into appropriate payment module that integrates with X-Cart 5 and does touches credit card data.